# How to migrate a field from a boxed version to an unboxed version

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I have a field that is a `Double`. I want to change it to a `double` field. Here's the code I have set up to do that:

```
schema.get("Item")
        .addField("mOriginalWeightUnboxed",double.class)
        .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
            @Override
            public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                Double boxedWeight=obj.get("mOriginalWeight");
                if (boxedWeight==null)
                    boxedWeight=0.0;
                obj.setDouble("mOriginalWeightUnboxed",boxedWeight.doubleValue());
            }
        })
        .removeField("mOriginalWeight")
        .renameField("mOriginalWeightUnboxed","mOriginalWeight");
```

Would this be a recommended way of doing that?

Comment: ..Does it work?

Comment: I actually think all you need to do is add a `@Required` annotation on your field, and via your migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double` and `double` are the same for Realm, except `double` is not nullable.

So if you want to make a `Double` into a `double`, then just make the field `@Required`, and add the annotation for it via migration as well.

```
schema.get("Item")
    .setNullable("mOriginalWeight", false);
```

Comment: this doesn't enable me to change the class field from `Double` to `double`

Comment: It should, because the only difference between `Double` and `double` is that the first is nullable. By setting your field to `nullable = false` you can switch the type to `double`.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior are you saying *realm* uses the same data structure for storing *java* `doubles` and `Doubles`-- the only difference being that `Doubles` in realm have the added capability of being null?